# Access to innerHTML of iframe

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, dom, iframe

I am trying to access the inner HTML of an iframe, where the source for the iframe is in the same domain.  When is use

```javascript
var pageSource = document.getElementById('iframeID');
```

and use inspect in the browser, I can see that `contentDocument.body.innerHTML` has the values I'm trying to grab.  However, if I try to access those values in the code, it's empty:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
<title>Test Stuff</title>
</head>
<body>


<div height=100 >This is a page:</div>

<div height=1600 >
<iframe name="iframeID" id="iframeID" width=1500 height=800 src="https://same.domain.asparent/otherpage"></iframe>
</div>

<div height=200><p id="sourceOut">Page source here.</p></div>

<script>

var pageSource = document.getElementById('iframeID').contentDocument.body.innerHTML;

document.getElementById("sourceOut").innerHTML = pageSource;
console.log(pageSource);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

`document.getElementById('iframeID').document.body.innerHTML` is not correct in this case.

I've tried Chrome, Edge and Firefox.  It appears to be something that the browser is doing.  Is it blocking access?  Why is this empty when I know there is something there?

For those who would question why I am doing this, the other page is just a test page to get this working.  I intend to replace that with a page that is proxied, order to grab the source from an external site.

Comment: Try using this line to get pageSource: ```var pageSource = document.getElementById('iframeID').innerHTML;```

Comment: Nope.  Doesn't work.  Using inspect, I can see what is defined and where, if I stop at getElemtnById.

Comment: Your code is trying to access the iframe content before it has been loaded and prepared.

Comment: @Ouroborus  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ourborus, this works:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
<title>Test Stuff</title>
</head>
<body>

<div height=100 >This is a page:</div>

<div height=1600 >
<iframe name="iframeID" id="iframeID" width=1500 height=800 src="https://same.domain.here/otherpage"></iframe>
</div>

<div height=200><p id="sourceOut">Page source here.</p></div>

<script>

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

}

async function getSource(){

await sleep(1000);
var pageSource = document.getElementById('iframeID').contentDocument.body.innerHTML;

document.getElementById("sourceOut").innerHTML = pageSource;
console.log(pageSource);

}

getSource();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```